# Quickbooks online app overrides Chrome "open last closed tab" shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, quickbooks-online

Quickbooks Online's web app for macros overrides Chrome's <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> command to open the last closed tab. Is there a way to make Chrome win this fight, or disable Quickbook's keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

### **option 1:**

- disable JavaScript

  [image]

### **option 2:**

- use an **[extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptblock/hcdjknjpbnhdoabbngpmfekaecnpajba)** and block individual scripts

### **option 3:**

- use **[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)** script:

  ```
  // ==UserScript==
  // @name           disable CTRL+SHIFT+T
  // @description    stop website from highjacking keyboard shortcuts
  //
  // @run-at         document-start
  // @include        *
  // @grant          none
  // ==/UserScript==

  keycodes = [84];

  (window.opera ? document.body : document).addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.ctrlKey) {
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
  return false;
  }, !window.opera);
  ```